# < followed by space or not in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a multi-line textbox, if I enter below string:

```
index a<3

2<x
```

By using regex I need to add space after character '<' if there is no space.
And if already have space after character '<' then keep as it is don't add additional space.

Expected result should be:

```
index a< 3

2< x
```

I tried `(?<=<)(?!$) and <[^\s]+`  these but giving syntax error, when used inside Javascript.

I can use them in back end(C#) but I don't want to put server request for it, as it not a good option.

Comment: Try this `'a<5'.replace(/<(?!\s+)/g,'< ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following approach *without regex* (ok, only little bit of regex used in `split`)

```js
document.querySelector( "textarea" ).addEventListener( "blur", function(){
  var value = this.value;
  //console.log( value );
  this.value = value.split( /\n|\r/ ).map( function(item){
    //console.log( item, item.split( /<|<\s/ ) );
    return item.split( /<\s|</ ).join( "< " );
  }).join( "\n" );
})
```

```html
Focus out of the below textarea to see the space added
<textarea>
index a<3 
index a<3 
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\S` to match any non-space character(which is a short handler for a negated character class, `[^\s]`). Since Javascript doesn't support look-behind you need to match `<` symbol followed by non-space character and then replace it with space contained `<` symbol.

```
str = str.replace(/<(?=\S)/g, '< ');

// or with negative lookahead
str = str.replace(/<(?!\s)/g, '< ');
```

```js
var str = 'index a<3\n2<x';


console.log(
  str.replace(/<(?=\S)/g, '< '),
  '\n\n',
  str.replace(/<(?!\s)/g, '< ')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following simple regex: `<\b` and replace it with `<` ('<' followed by a space)